# swift get final array from a completion block

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a completion block that is returning an Assync array from Firebase, the problem Im having is that the single array is printing each array as it retrieve them I only want to retrieve the final array when it is complete. How can i achieve this?

this is the result being printed

```
[["lat": 37.33150355, "long": -122.03071596]]
[["lat": 37.33150355, "long": -122.03071596], ["lat": 37.32550194, "long": -122.01974475]]
[["lat": 37.33150355, "long": -122.03071596], ["lat": 37.32550194, "long": -122.01974475], ["lat": 37.332431, "long": -122.030713]]
```

---

```
func dashMapView() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    mapView.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    mapView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myLocation", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New, context: nil)
    var helprInfo = [[String: AnyObject]]()
    currentIhelprInfo { (result) in
        //helprInfo = result
        helprInfo.append(result)
        print(helprInfo)
    }
}
// get curren Ihelper info
func currentIhelprInfo(completion: (result: [String: AnyObject]) -> ()) {
    var userAllInfo: [[String: AnyObject]]!
    let dbref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    dbref.child("users").queryOrderedByChild("receivePostRequest/status").queryEqualToValue(true).observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let request = child.childSnapshotForPath("receivePostRequest")
            var lat = request.value!["lat"] as! Double
            var long = request.value!["long"] as! Double
            var userInfo = [
                "lat": lat,
                "long": long
            ]
            //var userArray = userAllInfo.append(userInfo)
            completion(result: userInfo)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling your completion handler inside the for loop. Make sure to iterate over the data, do your logic first and finish it only when you have your `userInfo` array ready.

Your callback for `.observeEventType(.Value,` will look like the following:

```
var helprInfo = [[String: AnyObject]]()
for child in snapshot.children {
    let request = child.childSnapshotForPath("receivePostRequest")
    var lat = request.value!["lat"] as! Double
    var long = request.value!["long"] as! Double
    var userInfo = [
        "lat": lat,
        "long": long
    ]
    helprInfo.append(userInfo)
}
completion(result: helprInfo)
```

And your completion handler will only print the array passed in the completion handler.

```
currentIhelprInfo { (result) in
    print(result)
}
```